# siunitx.sty not found, local package repository for offline installation of MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, siunitx, offline

I try to create a offline repository for a MiKTeX installation. I have around 30 packages inside the repo and the only one which is not working is siunitx. I added the following files for siunitx to the repository because I didn't know which one is the right one and all of them include siunitx:

```
siunitx_source.tar.lzma
siunitx.tar.lzma
siunitx_doc.tar.lzma
```

I get the following failure during package installation:

```
! LaTeX Error: File siunitx.sty not found.
```

The strange thing is, I collected the packages form the MiKTeX folder from the Downloads for the offline installation with around 4GB (all packages). If I select folder with all packages for the installation, it is no problem including the siunitx.sty package, but I can't use the whole MiKTeX Folder with 4GB. I thought I might have to include another package which is connected to the siunitx package but I could found anything. Do yo have any ideas?

Comment: the middle one should be the right one. Did you ensure that the three  miktex-zzdbXXX-files are from the same source and the same date as the siunitx files? siunitx gets quite often updates and then you also need new zzdb files.

Comment: the problem was that miktex-zzdbXX files where not from the same source. Now the installation works fine, thanks you!